# Why only a DummyOperator task can run in my Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import time

dag_name = 'dagName'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date':datetime(2022,2,16),
    'schedule_interval':'@once',
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'catchup':False
}

with DAG(dag_name,default_args=default_args) as dag:

    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="start")

    t2 = BashOperator(task_id='hello_world',
                        bash_command='echo "Hi!!"')
    
    t3 = DummyOperator(task_id="end")
    
    t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

[image: task_status]

I have run this code on Apache Airflow 2. There is only the `start` task which marked as success while the `hello_world` task is still in `queued` status. I have check the task instance detail and it shows that : `Task is in the 'queued' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.` Then, I clear `hello_world` task, but the task is still in `queued` status. Is there any solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DummyOperator` doesn't have any actual code to execute so it's redundant to submit it to run on worker due to that reason Airflow has optimization that `DummyOperator` and any of its subclasses will not be sent to workers, they are automatically marked as Success by the scheduler (assuming no `on_execute_callback` is called etc..)

Your description means that you probably have some configuration not set up properly. This is not a DAG code issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I restarted my airflow scheduler, webserver, and worker. Now, all of my tasks are running.

Comment: Btw, several times, my task has an error and stops in success status. I cleared the task via `on_success_callback` function and then the task status changed to queued. I was only able to re-run my task after restarting the airflow scheduler, worker, and webserver. Is there any other way to restart the task automatically? Thank you